# Android: Firebase logout results in error

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

The Android Firebase logout always results in permission denied error.
I'm calling below signout() from Fragment.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

The error log as below:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: This client does not have permission to perform this operation
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:229)
```

Is there anything to be taken care before signing out from current firebase session?
Please guide, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any listeners attached to the database that are affected by security rules (for example, requiring the user to be signed in), those should be removed first before signing out.  Since we don't have any code to examine, this is only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an Authorization error.

It seems like You have a listener to `Database` that needs an authorization permission.
 And after `logout` You not remove that listener and it throws that exception. Find and remove that listener too :)

Comment: the `signOut()` is being called from a Fragment where it's ViewModel has a LiveData. So, tried calling `.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)` before signout() but no luck!

Comment: No, not `LiveData` observer. You have to remove Firebase Database (or Firestore) listener before you signout. Your exception have been thrown by Firebase Database/ Firestore